# mosquitto and ibm watson iot on raspberry pi Connection Refused

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, mosquitto, watson-iot

I am new to IoT. I just installed mosquitto on my rpi and registered my devices and gateway in Watson IoT Platform using this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/using-mosquitto-as-a-gateway-for-watson-iot/

Mosquitto works fine local mode. However, I am facing a problem subscribing/publishing using these commands:

```
 mosquitto_sub -d -h pxci52.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com  -i 'g:pxci52:myfstream:gateway' -t iot-2/type/myfstream/id/gateway/evt/status/fmt/raw
```

and

```
sudo mosquitto_pub -d -h pxci52.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com  -i 'g:pxci52:myfstream:gateway' -t iot-2/type/myfstream/id/gateway/evt/status/fmt/raw -m "hello"
```

Here is my conf file:

```html
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest topic


log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information

connection_messages true
log_timestamp true

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
connection bridge-to-watsoniot
address pxci52.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883
cleansession true
try_private false
bridge_attempt_unsubscribe false
notifications false
notification_topic iot-2/type/myfstream/id/gateway/evt/status/fmt/raw
remote_username token
remote_password xxxxxx
remote_clientid g:pxci52:myfstream:gateway
notifications true
topic iot-2/type/+/id/+/cmd/+/fmt/+ in iot-2/type/+/id/+/cmd/+/fmt/+
topic iot-2/type/+/id/+/evt/+/fmt/+ out iot-2/type/+/id/+/evt/+/fmt/+
connection_messages true
```

Comment: All 3 programs (mosquitto, mosquitto_sub & mosquitto_pub) are using the same client id, this won't work, each connection needs a unique id

Comment: Also you seam to have posted your password, in the config file. Best to delete this question and repost without the password as even if you edit the question the password will still be in the history

Comment: ps:its easier to delete the device and start new one its already for test purpose

Comment: even when i lunch the pub only dosen't connect !!

Comment: on the ibm terminal side i get => Invalid userID (token) for device auth: ClientID='d:pqci52:myfstream:gateway', ClientIP=41.***.**.*** 11 mai 2017 15:38:29
Closed connection from 41.***.**.***. The operation is not authorized. 2 times in the last 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in the log   Invalid userID (token) for device auth: ClientID='g:pqci52:myfstream:gateway'  Instead of just "token" try "use-token-auth"  That is what is specified in the recipe example you were following.

Comment: i tryed both even i inject it in the cmd to make sure                               `sudo mosquitto_pub -d -h pqci52.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -i 'g:pqci52:myfstream:gateway' -u  use-token-auth -P Nr0CHkXNbn3o+WFeMW -t iot-2/type/myfstream/id/gateway/evt/status/fmt/raw -m "hello" `     THANKS FOR YOUR HELP im switching to azure iothub i already wasted enaugh time on this

Comment: I checked the logs this morning and see Token auth failed (Device/gateway not found in database): ClientID='g:pqci52:myfstream:gateway'   so it's possible this device has not been registered as a gateway.

Comment: i appreciate it,  `Token auth succeeded: ClientID='d:pqci52:myfstream:gateway', ClientIP=************`                     
 using `mosquitto_pub -d -h pqci52.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -i 'd:pqci52:myfstream:gateway' -u use-token-auth -P Nr0CHkXNbn3o+WFeMW -t iot-2/type/myfstream/id/gateway/evt/status/fmt/raw -m "hello"`

Comment: So it is successful for you now trying to connect with d as device?

Comment: yep every thing seems correct exept i've created two devices one raspberry pi subscribing and other publishing, they connect right but i had i mistake im still figuring it out: Closed connection from ***********. The topic is not valid: iot-2/type/myfstream/id/s2/evt/status The topic does not match an allowed rule

Comment: A device can publish events and subscribe to commands:  iot-2/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string  If you want to monitor events, then you may need to connect an application to subscribe to that topic. https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/mqtt.html#mqtt